# LaTeX Symbol for random vector

Tags: symbols, math-fonts

I can not find the LaTeX command for the following symbol:

[image: symbol]

Anyone can help? It is an "X" with an horizontal line.

And I need also the command for:

[image]

Comment: `\mathfrak{X}` and `\mathfrak{Z}` (with the package `amssymb`).

Comment: Yes. Want to put it as an answer so I can accept?